# ASP.net MVC - Can I tell Html.Partial where to find the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view that lives in `/Views/Projects` and I am making a call to render a partial view:

```
@Html.Partial("_NotesPartial")
```

The view that  I want to render actually exists in the `/Views/Notes` folder but I can't figure out how to tell MVC to search that folder for this specific call. Is there an overload I can call to have MVC look for this view in this folder instead of Projects and Shared?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render partial from different folder (not shared)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208421/render-partial-from-different-folder-not-shared)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Can you pass in the full path?

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Projects/_NotesPartial.cshtml")
```

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that was possible :)