# Referencing a partial in Views/Shared asp.net

Tags: asp.net, partial-views

I found the following post: [Render partial from different folder (not shared)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208421/render-partial-from-different-folder-not-shared)

However this isn't working on my page.
The file structure is as follows:

```
>Areas
>>NewNavigation
>>>Views
>>>>Shared
>>>>>MyCustomView

>Views
>>Shared
>>>SignInLink
```

I want MyCustomView to be able to render the partial found in: `views/shared/signinlink`

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/SignInLink.ascx"); %>
```

Cannot resolve partial view

Answer (score 0):

Try `<% Html.RenderPartial("SignInLink"); %>`, as the mvc runtime will search the shared directory (this is built in):

> ... will search the partial view in different folder:
>
> The /Views/Home folder a file named “_MyPartial” (With aspx, ascx,
>   cshtml or vbhtml extension). The View/Shared folder a file named
>   “_MyPartial” (With aspx, ascx, cshtml or vbhtml extension).

http://coding-in.net/mvc-3-organize-your-partial-views/

Comment: This was what I had originally and gives the same error.