# CSHTML file outside Views folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and I want to put CSHTML files outside of Views Folder. While I can do so easily by adding the CSHTML files in my desired folder, I am not able to render partial view result from these files.

The folder structure I currently have is roughly as follows:
Root
|
|--Templates
|  |---Welcome.cshtml
|
|--Views
|  |---

I'm using the below syntax from one of the controller actions

```
    public ActionResult Welcome()
    {
        return PartialView("Welcome");
    }
```

However, doing so, razor is not able to locate the Welcome.cshtml. I have read about using a custom view engine to change the default search location etc. etc. but wondering if this just can be solved by addition configuration.

Comment: You can use a relative path and include the '.cshtml' extension.  Look at this post for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208421/render-partial-from-different-folder-not-shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the root-relative path when returning a View/PartialView. For example:

```
public PartialViewResult Welcome()
{
    return PartialView("~/Templates/Welcome.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm.
Just had to include following at the top of my partial cshtml
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage

Comment: That is a good answer, but if you wanted to customize places where MVC looks for views check out this article, it is a bit dated, but it has useful information [Configure The Views Search Location](http://theshravan.net/blog/configure-the-views-search-locations-in-asp-net-mvc/).