# Partial from other folder than shared

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, partial-views

I want to render partial view in my asp.net core application.

Earlier i was using `@Html.Partial()` function but VS suggested me to change it to normal `<partial>` and from that moment i am using it like that since i rendered only few partial views so i stored them in shared folder but now i started using it more often and problem i am having is i want to sort them in folders.

I looked at answers but all are using `@Html.Partial()` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208421/render-partial-from-different-folder-not-shared) one but no answer with normal `<patial>` tag.

I tired doing it like this:

`<partial name='~/Folder/View' model='new Model()'`
but it is not working just as any combination with/without `~ /` and other signs.

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: `InvalidOperationException: The partial view '~/Reservation/New' was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Reservation/New` When i put same view in shared folder and call it only by name it works

Comment: It seems your path for Partial View is not valid. Please try to specify the complete path from your app root. Like this ~/Areas/Admin/Views/StoreMenu/CreateOrEdit.cshtml

Comment: I was already trying it but not exactly.... Big hint is to add `.cshtml` at the end.... If you use it from shared folder you do not need it but like this you need it.

Comment: Please share your partial view complete path.

Comment: It's now `~/Views/Reservation/New.cshtml` and all time i was trying `~/Views/Reservatoin/New`

Answer (score 1):

The `name` attribute is required. It indicates the name or the path of the partial view to be rendered. When a partial view name is provided, the [view discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.2#view-discovery) process is initiated. That process is bypassed when an explicit path is provided. For all acceptable `name` values, see [Partial view discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2#partial-view-discovery).

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2